# Should I bundle the source code, build script and deployment script together?

Tags: version-control, continuous-deployment

Should I bundle the source code, build script and deployment script together? In my previous company, they are always bundled together, but there is always a problem that when the company add a new server, they need to change the deployment script and create a new build version, however, there is no change to the source code. I would like to see what is your company practice on the source control, build and deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practices for deployment are to have some standard system for that purpose.  Usually that system will have a standard way to enumerate what hosts are available and what versions of software are on each host, so any scripts necessary for deployment become agnostic to the machines in use.

Similarly, in many environments, deployment uses a set of standard techniques.  For example, it is common to use CI to run tests and then build one or more deployment artifacts, such as a tarball or container, and then all deploys using the same technique use the same deployment method (e.g. unpack the tarball into a directory named after the repository name), so in that case a deployment script may not even be necessary.  If you use a standard method and one *is* necessary, then obviously you should include it in your artifact (which means it's included in the source code) or in the configuration for the deployment system (which should be maintained as repository as well).

As to whether one should include source code depends on whether it's needed.  If you're deploying a project in a language like Python or Ruby, then obviously it will be needed.  However, if you're deploying a project in a compiled language like Go or Rust, then it probably is not, and your build artifacts will be smaller and easier to work with if you don't include it and just build a binary artifact during CI.